# Java 8 - ParallelStream forEach giving error while trying to create JSON Objects

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Am trying to creating two JSONObjects and value and getting it for the Arraylist.
Am using Java8 ParallelStream and forEach features for to achieve this.

Please find my code below, am not able to create two JSONobject in a single forEach method.

Error am getting like : `userlist cannot be resolved`

```
user_list.parallelStream().forEach((userlist) -> 
     purchaserDetail.put("Purchaser", userlist.getName()),
     purchaserDetail.put("Purchaser_Email", userlist.getEmail_address()) ) ;
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: updated with the error details. sorry that i have missed last time.

Comment: While agree with @Eran answer to wrap into {}, I don’t think that is thread safe , because the same object purchaserDetail is being put by parallel stream, don’t use parallel stream when want to put to same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple statements require curly braces:

```
user_list.parallelStream().forEach((userlist) -> {
     purchaserDetail.put("Purchaser", userlist.getName());
     purchaserDetail.put("Purchaser_Email", userlist.getEmail_address());});
```

You might want to use `forEachOrdered` if you care about the order in which the elements are put into `purchaserDetail`.

Comment: _You might want to use forEachOrdered if you care about the order..._. then it would be better to use `user_list.forEach(...)` rather than calling `parallelStream.forEachOrdered(...)` as there is no benefit here.

Comment: i do have to create new JSONObject() for every iteration for `purchaserDetail`

Comment: @Karthikeyan Are you still having a problem? It's not clear from your comment. If you do, please clarify. If `purchaserDetail` is a `JSONObject`, and you need to create a new one for each iteration, add `JSONObject purchaserDetail = new JSONObject();` as the first line of the body of the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

While agree with @Eran answer to wrap into {}. I don’t think that is thread-safe, because the same object purchaserDetail is being put by parallel stream, don’t use parallel stream when want to put to same object, unless the object being operated on is thread-safe implementation(i.e. ConcurrentHashMap)